# When "ng-select" clicked somewhere outside "dropdown" not closing

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

Angular 5 ng-select 2.0.0

How do I close "dropdown" when I click on an item other than "ng-select"?

> EDIT
>   https://angular-yiiyq6.stackblitz.io

> HTML

```
<ng-select placeholder="Seçiniz" [items]="people" bindLabel="name" bindValue="id" [virtualScroll]="true"></ng-select>
```

> TS

```
people = ['Ali', 'Veli', 'Ayşe', 'Fatma'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

version 2 is compatible with angular 6. I've updated the angular version and corrected the problem.